# Spring Boot Actuator - Error creating bean with name 'processorMetrics'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to run a Spring boot application on a Kubernetes cluster. Locally, the application runs and is available. I can hit endpoints on the local version. However, when deployed, the endpoints are not reachable.

Java 17

Spring Boot 3.0.2

spring-boot-starter-actuator 3.0.2

There is not a clear reason why the endpoints are not available. The only error I'm seeing in the logs is regarding metrics.

```
{"app":"MyApi","ts":"2023-02-10T22:25:49.141+00:00","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"ERROR","class":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","method":"reportFailure","file":"SpringApplication.java","line":820,"thread":"main","stack":"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processorMetrics' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics]: Factory method 'processorMetrics' threw exception with message: null\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)\n\tat com.mystuff.sync.myapi.MyApiApplication.main(MyApiApplication.java:12)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)\n\t... 3 frames truncated\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics]: Factory method 'processorMetrics' threw exception with message: null\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)\n\t... 27 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null\n\tat java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:263)\n\tat java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)\n\tat java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)\n\tat jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.lambda$readStringValue$1(CgroupUtil.java:67)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)\n\tat jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.readStringValue(CgroupUtil.java...","msg":"Application run failed"}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processorMetrics' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics]: Factory method 'processorMetrics' threw exception with message: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.mystuff.sync.myapi.MyApiApplication.main(MyApiApplication.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics]: Factory method 'processorMetrics' threw exception with message: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
```

Is there a way to disable collection of metrics? I have seen posts regarding this, and setting `management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=false` for spring-boot-actuator, but this has had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by disabling OpenTelemetry for the application. Obviously, we wanted to be able to collect metrics for the deployed application, but this was a temporary fix.
We resolved the OTel issue by upgrading the OTel Java Agent to v1.22. thehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746779/conflicts-between-springboot-jersey-and-splunk-otel-collector

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Could you explain how to disable OpenTelemetry? We are using spring-boot 3.1.4 and jdk17. Should we change actuator properties in application.properties?

Comment: We are not using any otel SDK. We are only using grafana.