# Conflicts between SpringBoot/Jersey and Splunk/OTel collector

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, spring-boot-actuator, open-telemetry

My organization is deploying an API that uses Spring Boot alongside Jersey. This is required because of a dependency that sets up some endpoints and uses Jersey, but our usual infrastructure supports Spring Boot based APIs.

In a local cluster, we were able to run the pod just fine. But, when deploying to our K8s cluster, the readiness/liveness probes failed and the pod entered a CrashLoopBackoff state. The liveness/readiness probes are set up using Spring Actuator.

However, we were able to deploy the application to the cluster when we **disabled our OTEL Agent** that sends metrics to Splunk. We do not see any port conflict with the OTEL Agent and the application. As far as we can tell, there may be some sort of conflict between the agent and Jersey, but we are stumped as to what.

Has anyone faced a similar issue with OpenTelemetry and SpringBoot/Jersey applications?

Some of the `application.properties`:

```
# These application properties allow Spring Boot Actuator to handle `/api/users/actuator/*` requests,
# while `/api/users/v2/*` requests will be handled by the application & Jersey endpoints
server.servlet.context-path=/api/users
spring.jersey.application-path=/v2
```

Using splunk_otel_java: https://github.com/signalfx/splunk-otel-java

Comment: what version of the OTel Java agent are you using? versions prior to [v1.19.0](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/tag/v1.19.0) have a big problem with newer versions of Spring Boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this issue by upgrading the OTel Java Agent to v1.22. It seems like the older version (1.18 in our case) had some sort of mysterious port conflict that wasn't obvious.

Comment: is there a way to check this in kubernetes? my springboot application is not coming up. I cant seem to find any services or pods with otel. Please help.